# PicketLink support for JBoss

Tags: jboss, jboss6.x, picketlink

> Download **JBoss EAP** or **WildFly**
>   PicketLink can be used on both servers.
>   Use the PicketLink Installer to configure them with the latest version
>   of the PicketLink modules and libraries.

Does this implicit mean

it will work on my `Red Hat JBoss Enterprise Application Platform - Version 6.4.5.GA`?

I can't find any further information about version support, maybe someone has experiences and could give me a hint.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

> **System Requirements**
>
> Make sure your environment is properly configured
> as follows:
>
> Java 1.6 or Java 1.7 PicketLink Federation Quickstarts JBoss
>
> **Enterprise Application Platform 6** or WildFly Servers.

[reference](http://picketlink.org/gettingstarted/saml_sso/)